# Why won't chromium load a PDF file but firefox will?

Tags: 14.04, chromium, pdf

I was on the url below using Chromium Version 41.0.2272.76 Ubuntu 14.04 (64-bit). A page at DMV's website and went to load the "CAP application" and kept getting the error message "Aw snap! something went wrong while displaying this page."

http://www.smogcheck.ca.gov/Consumer/Consumer_Assistance_Program/CAP_Frequently_Asked_Questions.html

So I went to my Firefox 37.0.1 browser that's also loaded on my machine and had no problem loading the page and printing out the application.

So I had a work around, but don't have a solution to this problem using ubuntu.

Comment: duplicate of [chrome-pdf-viewer-plugin](http://askubuntu.com/questions/12584/why-doesnt-chromium-have-chrome-pdf-viewer-plugin)

Comment: Werid, I haven't installed any plugins, but it opens pdf in chromium for me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the chrome web store now has [pdf.js](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/pdf-viewer/oemmndcbldboiebfnladdacbdfmadadm)